# Session timeout in React with modal

Tags: reactjs, session

I created a session time out using `react-idle-timer` it works perfect at the first time, but when I click on "continue session" in my modal warning, it does not reset the timeout to the original settings (30 seconds in this example). It keep opening the warning modal every 5 seconds after clicking on continue session.

SessionTimeout.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import IdleTimer from "react-idle-timer";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { actionCreators } from '../state/index';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import SessionTimeoutDialog from './SessionTimeoutDialog';

let countdownInterval;
let timeout = 1000 * 30 * 1;

const SessionTimeout = () => {
    const idleTimer = useRef(null);
    const history = useHistory();

    const login = useSelector((state) => state.login);  // this is just to see if a user is logged
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { logout } = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch); // this is to logout

    const [timeoutModalOpen, setTimeoutModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [timeoutCountdown, setTimeoutCountdown] = useState(0);

    const onActive = () => {
        // timer reset automatically.
        if (!timeoutModalOpen) {
            clearSessionInterval();
            clearSessionTimeout();
        }
    };
    
    const onIdle = () => {
        const delay = 1000 * 5;
        if(login.logged && !timeoutModalOpen) {
            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                let countDown = 60;
                setTimeoutModalOpen(true);
                setTimeoutCountdown(countDown);
                countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
                  if (countDown > 0) {
                    setTimeoutCountdown(--countDown);
                  } else {
                    handleLogout();
                  }
                }, 1000);
            }, delay);
        }
    };

    const clearSessionTimeout = () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
    
    const clearSessionInterval = () => {
        clearInterval(countdownInterval);
    };

    const handleLogout = () => {
        setTimeoutModalOpen(false);
        clearSessionInterval();
        clearSessionTimeout();
        logout();
        history.push("/login");
    };
      
    const handleContinue = () => {
        setTimeoutModalOpen(false);
        clearSessionInterval();
        clearSessionTimeout();
    };

    return (
        <>
          <IdleTimer
            ref={idleTimer}
            onActive={onActive}
            onIdle={onIdle}
            debounce={250}
            timeout={timeout}
          />
          <SessionTimeoutDialog
            countdown={timeoutCountdown}
            onContinue={handleContinue}
            onLogout={handleLogout}
            open={timeoutModalOpen}
          />
        </>
    );
};

export default SessionTimeout;
```

Here is my modal (dialog). SessionTimeoutDialog.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogActions,
  Button,
  Typography,
  makeStyles,
  Slide
} from "@material-ui/core";
import clsx from "clsx";
import red from "@material-ui/core/colors/red";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    dialog: {
      borderRadius: 0
    },
    button: {
      borderRadius: 0,
      textTransform: "none",
      padding: 5
    },
    logout: {
      color: "#fff",
      backgroundColor: red[500],
      "&amp;:hover": {
        backgroundColor: red[700]
      }
    },
    countdown: {
      color: red[700]
    }
}));

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props,ref) {
    return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

export default function SessionTimeoutDialog({
    open,
    countdown,
    onLogout,
    onContinue
}) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Dialog
            open={open}
            aria-labelledby="session-timeout-dialog"
            aria-describedby="session-timeout-dialog"
            classes={{ paper: classes.dialog }}
            TransitionComponent={Transition}
        >
            <DialogTitle id="session-timeout-dialog-title">
                Session Timeout
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <Typography variant="body2">
                    The current session is about to expire in{" "}
                    <span className={classes.countdown}>{countdown}</span> seconds.
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">{`Would you like to continue the session?`}</Typography>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button
                    onClick={onLogout}
                    variant="contained"
                    className={clsx(classes.logout, classes.button)}
                >
                Logout
                </Button>
                <Button
                    onClick={onContinue}
                    color="primary"
                    variant="contained"
                    className={classes.button}
                >
                    Continue Session
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}

SessionTimeoutDialog.propTypes = {
    /**
     * indicator whether the dialog is open/close
     */
    open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    /**
     * the countdown timer.
     */
    countdown: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    /**
     * callback function to handle closing action
     */
    onLogout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    /**
     * callback function to handle confirm action.
     */
    onContinue: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Here is a sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dust-dzt1t

How can I set the timeout back to the default 30 seconds or whatever I want after clicking on continue session?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useBnIdle` custom hook for the user idle detection. You can also restart the timer using `startTimer` function

```
npm i use-bn-idle
```

You can use `startTimer` function to start the user idle detection it accepts seconds as a parameter. The useBnIdle expects an arrow function as parameter which will execute if the user is idle for the specified time. you can write your logic in that function to show the modal.

The following example has restart button on click of it we can trigger the startTimer again with seconds. it will restart the user idle detection.

```
import {useBnIdle} from 'use-bn-idle';

const App = () => {
  const [startTimer, stopTimer] = useBnIdle(() => {
    //Will execute if the user is idle for a certain period of time.
    //You can write logic like showing popup or log out the user.
    console.log('Expired: Session Timeout');
  })
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // start the user idle detection
    startTimer(60); //passed 60 seconds as argument.
  })

  const restartTimer = () => {
     startTimer(30)
  }

  return <div>
    <button onClick={stopTimer}>Stop Detection</button>
    <button onClick={restartTimer}>Restart Timer</button>
  </div>
}
```